# Power BI: Formatting 'Measure' decimal number in Table

Tags: powerbi

I have a measure called %Q Change:

%Q Change = 100*(DIVIDE([Current Quarter Cost] - [Previous Quarter Cost], [Previous Quarter Cost]))

This calculates the percent change in cost usage from the previous quarter to the current quarter.

%Q Change is formatted as a decimal with 2 decimal places. 
I have a different measure called Analysis:

Analysis =

```
if([%Q Change] > 0, "There was a " & [%Q Change] & " increase in usage from last quarter",
```

When I display the Analysis measure in a table on my report, it has many more than 2 decimal places:

[image]

Analysis is formatted as text, so I'm not sure what to adjust to reduce the number of decimal places.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DAX format function, information is here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dax_functions/dax_format_function.htm